# zeebe as microservice orchestrator

Tags: microservices, single-sign-on, camunda, orchestration, zeebe

i'm wondering about using zeebe as a microservices orchestrator, so i have some questions..
in my case, i want to zeebe as workflow engine (microservices orchestrator) with some other microservices like (paymen, stor..)
so about my frontend lets say that i'll use angular, i've noticed that zeebe only provide grpc api, how to use rest to be compatible with angular?
what about authentication/authorization? could i use zeebe itself (like camunda) or i should develop a separate microservice for it (or using something like keycloak sso..) and how?
thanks all

i've searched for many solutions but everything seems blur for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use client libraries in different languages (including JavaScript) to access the Camunda APIs. Here is a list: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-clients/working-with-apis-clients/

Using for instance the java client in your backend you can expose a REST service to start your process to your (Angular) front end like:

```
  @IsAuthenticated
  @PostMapping("/{bpmnProcessId}/start")
  public void startProcessInstance(
      @PathVariable String bpmnProcessId, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> variables) {

    LOG.info("Starting process `" + bpmnProcessId + "` with variables: " + variables);

    zeebe
        .newCreateInstanceCommand()
        .bpmnProcessId(bpmnProcessId)
        .latestVersion()
        .variables(variables)
        .send();
  }
```

To work with the task API without graphQL another client library exists. Example: https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-8-lowcode-ui-template/blob/main/src/main/java/org/example/camunda/process/solution/facade/TaskController.java

You can find the full example application (uses React, but concepts are same) here: https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-8-lowcode-ui-template/tree/main/src/main/java/org/example/camunda/process/solution/facade

Comment: so i should have an extra layer to expose my zeebe api?

Comment: yes, having a facade is a good approach due to abstraction, security aspects like CSRF, protocol translation, use case / domain-specific services, exposing multiple APIS under same endpoint

Comment: for this case, i think it is useless to use keycloak as an sso so i can use the spring instance instead, what you think?

Comment: You could disable Identity (incl. KC) and use e.g. Spring Security to secure the facade, yes. Only thing is that you would also have to consider the SSO for the webapps like Operate.

Comment: using operate in my case should be for limited admin access (monitoring)

Comment: sure, you deserve it